# Dependency conflicts, while installing qt via conan

Tags: qt, cmake, dependencies, ubuntu-18.04, conan

I have a problem with installing and using qt via conan.
The actual error looks like below:

```
WARN: glib/2.58.3@bincrafters/stable: requirement zlib/1.2.11 overridden by qt/5.13.0@bincrafters/stable to zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable 
WARN: pcre/8.41: requirement zlib/1.2.11 overridden by glib/2.58.3@bincrafters/stable to zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable 
ERROR: Conflict in pcre/8.41
    Requirement bzip2/1.0.8 conflicts with already defined bzip2/1.0.8@conan/stable
    To change it, override it in your base requirements
```

My `conanfile.txt`:

```
[requires]
gtest/1.8.1@bincrafters/stable
boost/1.70.0@conan/stable
jsonformoderncpp/3.7.0@vthiery/stable
qt/5.13.0@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake

[options]
qt:with_mysql=False
```

I managed to resolve this dependency by adding `bzip2/1.0.8@conan/stable` to `[requires]` section, but than my application is missing fonts, that are mandatory:

```
QFontDatabase: Cannot find font directory /home/<user>/.conan/data/qt/5.13.0/bincrafters/stable/package/82f32da7b204a38af07f00f05f94ebbfd7454b77/lib/fonts.
Note that Qt no longer ships fonts. Deploy some (from https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/ for example) or switch to fontconfig.
```

This `fonts` directory is actually missing. Please note, that this project builds and run without such problems on other coworkers, same machines.

The question is - what causes those problems and how to resolve them?

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies conflict should be solved by switching to qt/5.13.1@bincrafters/stable, because a lot of dependencies have migrated to conan center.
Regarding the fonts issue, I'm in the process of adding an optional dependancy on fontconfig/2.13.1@conan/stable in the qt recipe. In the meantime, you could try to install system version of fontconfig, rebuild the qt recipe, and check the output to see if has "Fontconfig ............................. yes"